# Show that the intersection of any two distinct Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G$ has order $8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Suppose that $G$ is a group of order $48.$ Show that the intersection of any two distinct Sylow $2$-subgroups of G has order $8.$

Let $H,K$ be two distinct Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G.$ Then $$O(H\cap K)=\dfrac{O(H)O(K)}{O(HK)}=\frac{2^4\times2^4}{O(HK)}$$ where $O(HK)$ simply means number of elements in the set $HK.$

Since any two Sylow $2$-subgroups are conjugate to each other $K=gHg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G.$

Also $H,K$ being distinct subgroups of $G,$ $g\notin H.$ Thus $$O(H\cap K)=\dfrac{O(H)O(K)}{O(HK)}=\frac{16\times16}{O(gHg^{-1}.K)}$$

Since $O(H\cap K)|2^4$ and $H\ne K$ the possible values of $O(H\cap K)$ are $1,2,4,8.$ I don't know how to reject the possibilities of $1,2,4.$

Please help.

Comment: $HK$ is a union of cosets of $H$, so $|HK| = 16,32$ or $48$. By your first formula, $|HK|=16$ means $H=K$, $|HK|=32$ means intersection of order 8, and $|HK|=48$ is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this outline should work : Assuming that there isn't a unique $2-$Sylow subgroup, there have to be 3. Let $G$ act on the set of $2-$Sylow subgroups by conjugation. This gives a homomorphism
$$
\varphi : G\to S_3
$$
It shouldn't be too hard to check that this map is surjective, and so $\ker(\varphi)$ has order 8.

Check that $\ker(\varphi)$ is contained in any $2-$Sylow subgroup (since it is contained in one 2-sylow subgroup).

Hence, $\ker(\varphi)$ is contained in $H\cap K$, and so $|H\cap K| \geq 8$.

By what you have, $|H\cap K| \leq 8$, which proves your result.

Comment: How do you conclude that $ker(\phi)$ is contained in any 2-Sylow subgroup?

Comment: Any $p$-subgroup is contained in a $p-$Sylow subgroup. $\ker(\varphi)$ has order 8, so it is contained in some group of order 16. Now use the fact that it is normal to conclude that it is contained in all $2-$Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Ah, clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

How about this easier solution?

Note that $48=2^4\cdot 3$.
Since $H\cap K\leq H$ and $|H|=16$,
by Lagrange's Theorem, 
$|H\cap K|\in \{1,2,4,8,16\}$.

If $|H\cap K|\in \{1,2,4\}$, 
then $|HK|=\frac{|H|\cdot |K|}{|H\cap K|}\geq 48=|G|$.

If $|H\cap K|=16$, 
then $H=K$, 
contrary to the assumption.

Thus, $|H\cap K|=8$.

Comment: Great!This answer is more slicker! Thanks!

Comment: @W.Leywon It is from Example 37.13 in Fraleigh's _A First Course in Abstract Algebra_. A similar problem is Lemma 6.10 in Hungerford's _Algebra_

Answer (score 0):

O(G)=48=2^4.3
Number of 2-SSG=1+2k and should divide 3 so the possibilities can be 1or 3 and order of 2-SSG is 16
Let H,K be the two distinct 2-SSG then
48>|HK|=|H||K|/|H intersection K|
from above we can conclude that |H intersection K|>5
|H intersection K| divides |H| and |K| but |H intersection K| cannot be 16 as H and K are distinct.So |H intersection K|=8